# Grid System in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to display 3 white blocks in a blue container. Each with a 10px margin between.

Currently I have this:

```html
<div class="wbg-create">
                <div class="full-create">
                  <div class="white-create">
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <t class="f30 helv grey">Create Group</t>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <t class="f30 helv-b grey">Group Name</t>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input class="gen-input helv-b">
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <t class="f30 helv-b grey">Array Type</t>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <select class="gen-input helv txtind-10">
                      <option>Option 1</option>
                      <option>Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <button class="b_next"><b>Next</b></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="white-create" style="margin: 0 auto;"></div>
                </div>

              </div>
```

```css
.wbg-create{
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    background-color: #f3fbff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 98vh;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.f30{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.helv{
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}
.helv-b{
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.grey{
    color: #545454;
}
.gen-input{
    background-color: #e3e8ed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.txtind-10{
    text-indent: 10px;
}
.full-create{
    margin: 10px;
}
.white-create{
    left: 50%;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 96vh;
}
.b_next{
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #cad2e7;
    color: #28284c;
    border-color: transparent;
    bottom: 30px;
}

.b_next:hover{
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #dde7ff;
    color: #4e4e95;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.b_next:active{
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #30a3f5;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

I know this is really messy, and I should be using `margin` and `padding` instead of `<br/>` but I find it a very long process. My web-app is only run in full-screen and cannot be resized, so it shouldn't be too much of a problem.

How do I get these containers to appear side-by-side?
Currently, there are side-by-side, but they appear below the previous one.

Like this:

```
[]-should be here-
  []
    []
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: _How do I get these containers to appear side-by-side?_ which containers are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack:

```
.white-create{display:inline-block;}
```

Better:

Have a look at [Common CSS Flexbox Layout Patterns with Example Code](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/common-flexbox-patterns/)

More infos: [MDN flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Using grid.

```
.wbg-create {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Here's a pen with the working answer. 
https://codepen.io/jorgeberen/pen/wvKVBNN

Using flex should do the trick too.

```
.wbg-create {
display: flex;
}
```

Because `display:flex` displays the items within the container by default in a horizontal row, your three white blocks should be displayed side by side. For this case scenario it is simpler than using grid.